# Delete Object From An Array Of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, socket.io

I Have an Array of objects like this

```
var persons = [
  {p_id:1000, name:"jhon", age:25, sex:"male"},
  {p_id:1001, name:"lisa", age:30, sex:"female"},
  {p_id:1002, name:"robert", age:29, sex:"male"}
]
```

I want to delete person where the key is p_id = 1001 (lisa) so my array become :

```
var persons = [
  {p_id:1000, name:"jhon", age:25, sex:"male"},
  {p_id:1002, name:"robert", age:29, sex:"male"}
]
```

note :
- Not using jquery because this is server side javascript (node.js)

Comment: Try `Array.prototype.filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Taylor pointed out from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array), you can get the index and use splice() to remove it.  Here is the code:

```
var persons = [
  {p_id:1000, name:"jhon", age:25, sex:"male"},
  {p_id:1001, name:"lisa", age:30, sex:"female"},
  {p_id:1002, name:"robert", age:29, sex:"male"}
];

var index = -1;
for (var i = 0, len = persons.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (persons[i].p_id === 1001) {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
}

if (index > -1) {
  persons.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(persons);  // output and array contains 1st and 3rd items
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Array.prototype.splice`:

```js
var persons = [
  {p_id:1000, name:"jhon", age:25, sex:"male"},
  {p_id:1001, name:"lisa", age:30, sex:"female"},
  {p_id:1002, name:"robert", age:29, sex:"male"}
]
persons.splice(0,1);
console.log(persons); //-> array without the first element
```

Here's some documentation: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the item with p_id=1001 you can use `filter()`:

```
persons = persons.filter(function(item) { return item.p_id !== 1001; });
```

Comment: This does not remove the item from the existing array. This creates a new array with the item excluded. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter